# How to have one to one chat using firebase in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, chat

I am trying to have a one to one chat feature using firebase. Right now, my structure of messages makes sense in the fb database but I am not able to implement one to one chat feature using firebase's api in angular. I am able to spam a chat room where all the users can see everyone's messages but i would like to have a one to one chat feature in my application. My structure is good in the firebase database and i just need to manipulate my javascript code to make it work. My code is as follows.

```
function chatController($scope,$firebaseArray) {

    var ref1=firebase.database().ref().child('users/59c1c11cec/chats/-KuRshPYbO_d9B');
    $scope.chats=$firebaseArray(ref1); 
    var ref=firebase.database().ref().child('chats/-KuRshPYbO_d9B/messages');
    $scope.messages=$firebaseArray(ref);
    $scope.send=function(){
        $scope.messages.$add({
            message:$scope.messageText,
         //   date:Date.now()
        })
    }
}
```

I am able to create a one to one chat between two users by hard coding their user ids, but I was wondering if firebase's api is able to do this dynamically. If yes, how would I do it? For reference, 59c1c11cec is the current logged in user id, -KuRshPYbO_d9B is the other person's id who the current person is starting a conversation with which I don't have any access to in my own database but only in firebase's database. And using that users id I retrieve the messages between the two users. How will I be able to achieve this? I just need to replace the hard coded values with the values I talked about.Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You can [get the UID of the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) with `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid`. Getting the ID of the other user is app specific. You'll likely want to show a list of contacts that the current user can start a chat with.

Comment: In my case, a chat object is created in the database when a match is created just like tinder. The corresponding matching of the current user id I need to get. Firebase doesn't provide that ?